# Hide page title from all pages, refinerycms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms, refinery

I am using `refinerycms 2.1.0`. How can i remove page `"Company name"` title from all pages,
I  overrided home page then passed :hide_sections => :body_content_title to render
 '/refinery/content_page'. But it is not working.

From guides, one of the chief maintainers of Refinery CMS, says:

> Add a content_for :body_content_title block in  the template you’re
>   including from. Just make it blank and tell the _content_page partial
>   to hide empty sections by passing it :locals => {:hide_sections =>
>   [:body_content_title]}.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be trying to remove the site name from the header. Give this a try...

```
$ rake refinery:override view=refinery/_header.html
```